# SQL Join with the Same table with out Pivot Table

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, t-sql

I have a problem, I'm trying to join the same table and make column of it. For example the table contains `id`, `name`, `type`.

And the data can be:

```
id          name            type            Date 
--------------------------------------------------
1           KKKK            BP          05/05/2017 
2           MMMM            KS          07/10/2016 
3           LLL             TL          04/05/2017 
4           NNN             BP          06/01/2016
```

I want to make a table with the following design:

```
- id   name      BP                 KS                   TL  
-------------------------------------------------------------
1      KKK    05/05/2017 
2      MMM                       07/10/2016  
3      LLL                                           04/05/2017 
4      NNN    06/01/2017
```

I tried Pivot table and didn't work.

Any idea?

Comment: Please show us your TSQL attempt at solving this problem.  Thanks!

Comment: The problem with the pivot is that can be 26 different types and one name can have the same class and different dates , so with that case I want to do a extra column with it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the [`PIVOT`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/queries/from-using-pivot-and-unpivot) function in SQL Server 2008 to convert your rows of data into columns:

```
select 
  id,
  name,
  BP, KS, TL
from
(
  select id, 
    name,
    type,
    [date]
  from mytable
) d
pivot
(
  max([date])
  for type in (BP, KS, TL)
) piv;
```

This could also be written using conditional logic, like a `CASE` expression with some aggregation:

```
select id,
  name,
  BP = max(case when type = 'BP' then [date] end),
  KS = max(case when type = 'KS' then [date] end),
  TL = max(case when type = 'TL' then [date] end)
from mytable
group by id, name;
```

Based on your comment that you could have multiple dates for each `name` and `type` combination, you can still use similar queries you'll just have to use a windowing function like [`row_number`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/row-number-transact-sql) to get the final result you want.

If you want to use the conditional logic version, you'd change the query to be:

```
select 
  name,
  BP1 = max(case when type = 'BP' and rn =1 then [date] end),
  BP2 = max(case when type = 'BP' and rn =2 then [date] end),
  BP3 = max(case when type = 'BP' and rn =3 then [date] end),
  KS1 = max(case when type = 'KS' and rn =1 then [date] end),
  KS2 = max(case when type = 'KS' and rn =2 then [date] end),
  TL1 = max(case when type = 'TL' and rn =1 then [date] end)
from 
(
  select 
    name,
    [type], 
    [date],
    rn = row_number() over(partition by name, [type] order by [date] desc)
  from mytable
) d
group by name;
```

The PIVOT version would be:

```
select 
  name,
  BP1, BP2, BP3, KS1, KS2, TL1
from
(
  select 
    name,
    type = type + cast(rn as varchar(2)),
    [date]
  from
  (
    select 
      name,
      type,
      [date],
      rn = row_number() over(partition by name, [type] order by [date] desc)
    from mytable
  )s
) d
pivot
(
  max([date])
  for type in (BP1, BP2, BP3, KS1, KS2, TL1)
) piv;
```

As you can see there is a lot of typing to get all of these columns, so you could use dynamic SQL to get the final result:

```
DECLARE @cols AS NVARCHAR(MAX),
    @query  AS NVARCHAR(MAX)

select @cols = STUFF((SELECT ',' + QUOTENAME(Type + cast(rn as varchar(2))) 
                    from
                    (
                      select type,
                        rn = row_number() over(partition by name, type order by date desc)
                      from mytable
                    ) d
                    group by type, rn
                    order by type, rn
            FOR XML PATH(''), TYPE
            ).value('.', 'NVARCHAR(MAX)') 
        ,1,1,'')

set @query = N'SELECT name, ' + @cols + N' 
            from 
            (
                select 
                  name,
                  type = type + cast(rn as varchar(2)),
                  [date]
                from
                (
                  select 
                    name,
                    type,
                    [date],
                    rn = row_number() over(partition by name, [type] order by [date] desc)
                  from mytable
                )s
            ) x
            pivot 
            (
                max(date)
                for type in (' + @cols + N')
            ) p '

exec sp_executesql @query;
```

I created a [demo](https://data.stackexchange.com/stackoverflow/query/669694) to show that they all return the same result.

Comment: The Type is a table and its have 25 different type,  also some times  the same name have same type and different date  so i want to make another column with it.

Comment: @Luis64 What do you mean "some times the same name have same type and the same date"?  You should include these details in your original question, please edit you question with some sample data that shows this and then the final desired result.

Comment: Same name, same class ,different days, so I want to make a extra column with it

Comment: @Luis64 What is `class` your sample data doesn't include anything called that? what do you mean extra column? Edit your question with additional details, including more sample data and the desired result.

Comment: Sorry the Type is  class=type  sorry about that

Comment: The Problem for Do Pivot is you need a max to do it , in this case the name can have multiple dates in the same type so I need to do a extra column of it

Comment: @Luis64 You say multiple dates, how many are you talking about?  One? Two? Three? Unlimited?

Comment: Hello Ollie, thanks to give me help , can be 3 or 4 dates

Comment: @Luis64 See my edit with a few new ways to get the answer.

Comment: Ollie you are my hero.  I got a small error but I going to solve it .Msg 8114, Level 16, State 1, Line 21
Error converting data type nvarchar to datetime.

Comment: @Luis64 Hmm are you using the code as written? What are that datatypes on your table?

Comment: Date =Datetime,Type= Nvarchar(255), Name=Nvarchar(max),id=bigint

Comment: yes, I using the last one , the one is dynamic, also I got this error from one of the type, @cols : [CC1],[CC:' is not a valid identifier.

Comment: @Luis64 It's really hard to debug your code when you provided very little sample data.

Comment: I know , the problem is this information is confidential :( , but I am Working in yours code to see what I can do... Thanks so much OLLIE .. you are the best  :)

Comment: @Luis64 I'd work with the hard-coded version first to make sure the data looks ok, then use the dynamic sql once you've worked out all the bugs.

Comment: I will thanks ollie, I hope I can solve a SQL problem to you one day ..regards